# OpenCL overlap communication and computation

Tags: opencl, communication, nvidia, overlap, computation

There is an example in OpenCL NVIDIA SDK, oclCopyComputeOverlap, that uses 2 queues to alternatively transfer buffers / execute kernels. 
In this example mapped memory is used.

```
**//pinned memory** 
cmPinnedSrcA = clCreateBuffer(cxGPUContext, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, szBuffBytes, NULL, &ciErrNum);
**//host pointer for pinned memory**
fSourceA = (cl_float*)clEnqueueMapBuffer(cqCommandQueue[0], cmPinnedSrcA, CL_TRUE,    CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, szBuffBytes, 0, NULL, NULL, &ciErrNum);
...
**//normal device buffer**
cmDevSrcA = clCreateBuffer(cxGPUContext, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, szBuffBytes, NULL, &ciErrNum);
**//write half the data from host pointer to device buffer**
ciErrNum = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(cqCommandQueue[0], cmDevSrcA, CL_FALSE, 0, szHalfBuffer, (void*)&fSourceA[0], 0, NULL, NULL);
```

I have 2 questions:
1) Is there any need to use pinned memory for the overlap to occur? Couldn't fSourceA be just a simple host pointer,

```
fSourceA = (cl_float *)malloc(szBuffBytes);
...
//write random data in fSourceA
```

2) cmPinnedSrcA is not used in the kernel, instead cmDevSrcA is used. Doesn't the space occupied by the buffers on the device still grow? (space required for cmPinnedSrcA added to the space required for cmDevSrcA)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question properly:

1)
 Yes, you can use any kind of memory (pinned, host pointer, etc..) and the overlap will still occur. As far as you use two queues and the HW/drivers supports it.

But remaind that, the queues are always unsynced. And in this case, events are needed to prevent the copy queue to copy non-consistent data of the running kernel.

2) I think you are using 2 times the memory if you use pinned memory, one for the pinned and another one for a temporary copy. But I am not 100% sure, maybe it is only a pointer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But I still don't understand the following: 1)Why is he using pinned memory there, since the schema is like this: create 3 pinned buffers, pinnedA,pinnedB,pinnedResult; create pinned pointers, flA, flB,flResult; create 3 normal buffers, A, B, Result; enqueue write from host pointer flA to A (half the size), write from flB to B (half the size) in Queue 1;enqueue kernel K1 in Queue 1, enqueue write from flA to A (other half), write from flB to B(other half) in Queue 2;

Comment: enqueue read from Result(first half) to flResult in Queue 1, enqueue kernel K2 in Queue 2; enqueue read Result (other half) in Queue 2. The kernels use only A, B, Result as buffers. 2)I was referring to size of pinned buffers (pinnedA, pinnedB, pinnedResult) that adds to the size of the others (A, B, Result). Anyway, thank you again for answering so quickly

Comment: I don't really know in details how pinned works. But that usage method is the typical for pinned memory.